# Java Generics - An Issue with Type Erasure?

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I have a generic class, `CodominantPopulation`, which is a subclass of another generic class, `SexualPopulation`, which is itself a subclass of a generic class (`Population`). The aforementioned classes are defined as follows:

```
public class CodominantPopulation<O extends CodominantOrganism> extends SexualPopulation<O> {

public CodominantPopulation(List<O> organisms) {
        super(organisms);
    }
    ...
}

public class SexualPopulation<O extends SexualOrganism> extends Population<O> {
    public SexualPopulation(List<O> organisms){
        super(organisms);
    }
    ...
}
```

The `CodominiantOrganism` above is a subclass of `SexualOrganism`, which is itself a subclass (as may be expected) of an `Organism`. Within `CodominantPopulation`, I call a function that is only available to `CodominantOrganisms`, called as follows:

```
// in CodominantPopulation
for (O organism : population){
    // organism must be a CodominantOrganism
    CodominantGenotype.Dominance dominance = organism.getTraitDominance(trait);
    ...
}
```

Nonetheless, the runtime throws:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: SexualOrganism cannot be cast to util.CodominantOrganism
    at CodominantPopulation.countDominance(CodominantPopulation.java:xx)
        ...
```

I am not exactly sure how to interpret/fix this error. I have done some research and it seems as though this could be related to Java's type erasure - is this possible? I am passing objects of type `CodominantOrganism` to `CodominantPopulation` before the program is compiled.

Edit: The definition for `Population` is as follows:

```
public class Population<O extends Organism> {
    List<O> population;

    public Population(List<O> organisms){
        this.population = new ArrayList<>();
        this.population.addAll(organisms);
    }
    ...
}
```

Comment: What is `population`?  I see that you pass `organisms` to `super` in your constructors.  Perhaps it's something like a `List<O>` in the `SexualPopulation` class, in which case type erasure makes the casted type of `O` in your enhanced `for` loop to be `SexualOrganism`.

Comment: The compiler is not throwing this exception.  The runtime is throwing it.  The type `O` is correctly resolving to `CodominantOrganism` at compile time, so there must be some other non type safe shenanigans going on at runtime.

Comment: Noted, Judge Mental. And rgettman, `Population` has been added to the post above.

Comment: @nmagerko What happens when you change `for (O organism : population){` to `for (CodominantOrganism organism : population) {`?

Comment: The variable called `population`, not the class, is what we need.  But I contend that the fact that this code compiles and runs at all means you're doing something else unkosher.  "Erasure", while an abomination, is probably the wrong punching bag in this case.

Comment: `Population` (the class) has the protected variable `population` (see the edit above). And if it is not erasure, is there something else that I can look for?

Comment: Hint: Look at your `ArrayList` type parameter!

Comment: This is a great use case for single step debugging.  The code calling `getTraitDominance` compiles.  Figure out how you managed to convince the compiler to allow a list of `Organism` to be treated as a list of `CodominantOrganism` by stepping through the code until you hit the unsafe cast or array operation.

Comment: I will start debugging in that manner, Judge Mental. As for the ArrayList type parameter, I don't believe that there is an issue with not using the explicit `new ArrayList<O>();` syntax.

Comment: Debugging shows nothing more than the error string does, unfortunately. It does look, however, as though the `Population` is creating a `population` with type `SexualOrganism`, as the error says there is. I thought, though, my generics would stop this from occurring?

Comment: Exactly which line is causing the exception, the for loop out the call to getTraitDominance (or something else?)

Comment: When I debug by single steps, it shows that the for loop causes the cast exception. Essentially, casting the object in `population` to `O` is causing the exception. Could this be an issue with the access level of `population`? It is currently protected, and defined in Population (as seen above)

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that is less an issue with generic types, but with *inheritance*, based on passing a not yet ready object to a super. Maybe you have factory methods or constructors that try to pass a not yet made `CodominantOrganism`.

This can happen is several ways.

```
class A
    A (X y) { f(y); }
    protected void f(X x) { }

class B
    B (X y) { super(y); f(y); }
    @Override
    protected void f(X x) { }
```

Here the in A's constructor indeed B's f is called, but with an unready B.

With a bit of luck the IDE warns about using non-final methods in the constructor, but other patterns of the same kind are possible. Maybe use FindBugs for checking code inconsistencies.

*I might be wrong, but generic types does not seem the culprit.*

Comment: I will certainly take that into consideration - I do have a factory method, and I believe it was static, but I will check on whether or not there are other methods that could be related to your suggestion.